# How to implement total count over multiple partitions in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Let's say we have an inData Topic with 5 Partitions, that contains contract data and the contractId as key. I have 3 instances of a Kafka streams application, which counts the number of contracts.

Now I want to implement a total count of contracts in my Kafka streams application. 
Now I read that each stream application is assigned to only one partition. That means, that each instance of the Kafka streams application has only the count of each partition?

How can be a total count of contracts implemented? Do I need an intermediate topic with only one partition? Can it be achieved using a globalTable?

Comment: You can use a global table, yes. Where are you stuck with trying this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `GlobalKTable` or global state store wouldn't work (at least not directly), because both can only store unmodified data from a topic, however, you want to do some processing (ie, counting).

If you want to count all unique `contactId` you should first load the data into a `KTable` (via `builder.table()`) and afterward do a `groupBy().count()` -- in the `groupBy()` you map all record to the same new key. Because all records are mapped to the same key they will be repartitioned to the same topic partition and thus you get a global count.

Comment: J Sax. Where does the GlobalKTable maintains the dataStore ? Is it being replicated across all stream-tasks ??

Comment: The store is replicated per _instance_ (ie, `KafkaStreams` client), not per task. Each `KafkaStreams` instance will create a local RocksDB store and read data from all global-topic partitions into the store.

Comment: J sax.  But Is this not against the fundamentals of Kafka itself ? As evident from Consumer's point of view, 2 different consumers can never be subscribed to the same partition, although 1 consumer can very well read from multiple partitions.

Comment: Well, if you use consumer group management yes. To make this "broadcast" pattern possible, Kafka Stream uses manual partition assignment though and uses a second consumer without a `group.id` to consume "global" topics.

Comment: Alright, got it. Thank you very much. This is really appreciable and nice of you.. Can you kindly help me at this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64285276/kafka-streaming-tasks-and-management-of-internal-state-stores

Comment: Still don't understand. If you use a KTable, each stream instance will consume data from only 1 partition of the input topic. So each instance will not store a global count but rather a count of the consumed partition, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, but the idea is to re-map everything to the same key -> `in the groupBy() you map all record to the same new key` -- ie, you have a partitioned "input" KTable, and apply a group-by to map to a single key to get a non-partitioned output KTable with the overall count (it's of course not every efficient, but the only way to do it).